# phonegap - sqlite database question

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Do phonegap sqlite databases show up in the Safari databases tab under settings on the iphone?

When I test my app in safari on the iphone (not a compiled phonegap app) the sqlite database my app creates shows up in the databases section on the iphone so I can remove it if I want to so I'm curious to know if the same thing happens with phonegap apps that create sqlite databases. Or are the databases stored with the actual app so a user can not optionally delete it.

Answer (score 2):

if you used the javascript HTML5 storage, then the database will be visible.

you can write your own code/plugin to utilize phoneGap and the device sqllite database storage